# High dimensional regression overfitting

Tags: regression, predictive-models, prediction, overfitting, high-dimensional

Consider the linear regression model 
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}
\end{equation}
where we assume $\boldsymbol{X}$ is $n$-by-$p$, with $p > n$, and $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ independent of $\boldsymbol{X}$.

If we let $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ denote the **training** and **development** (or testing) data respectively and let $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ be an estimate of $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ obtained using the training data, we'll generally expect 
\begin{equation}
Cor(\boldsymbol{X}^{\mathcal{T}}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}, \boldsymbol{y}^{\mathcal{T}}) > Cor(\boldsymbol{X}^{\mathcal{D}}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}, \boldsymbol{y}^{\mathcal{D}}) 
\end{equation}
since this can be explained by $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ being overfitted to the error $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{\mathcal{T}}$ in the training data. However, I believe it is also generally true that 
\begin{equation}
Cor(\boldsymbol{X}^{\mathcal{T}}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}, \boldsymbol{X}^{\mathcal{T}}\boldsymbol{\beta}) > Cor(\boldsymbol{X}^{\mathcal{D}}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}, \boldsymbol{X}^{\mathcal{D}}\boldsymbol{\beta}) 
\end{equation}
Has anyone provided a theoretical explanation of the phenomenon? In fact, any theoretical discussion of overfitting in linear models is welcome.

Comment: In the theory of linear models, $X\beta$ are considered known constants, so their correlation with any random variable is zero. The $y_i$ are considered random.

Comment: There is a lot of literature out there that assumes X is random also, e.g. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2345402

Comment: right, then you should include that important assumption in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one way to look at it is to see that if we estimate the model parameters using a Mean Squared Error (MSE) loss, then we seek to minimize $(y^{\mathcal{T}} - X^{\mathcal{T}}\hat{\beta})$. If $p > n$, then we often can get a perfect fit. Thus, generally, $(y^{\mathcal{T}} - X^{\mathcal{T}}\hat{\beta})$ is an overfit as compared to $(y^{\mathcal{D}} - X^{\mathcal{D}}\hat{\beta})$.

Note that this is not because of an overfit to $\epsilon^{\mathcal{T}}$. You may even argue that $\hat{\beta}$ is overfitted with respect to $\epsilon^{\mathcal{T}}$ *only because* $X^{\mathcal{T}}\hat{\beta}$ is over-fitted with respect to $y^{\mathcal{T}}$. Thus the overfit of $X^{\mathcal{T}}\hat{\beta}$ to $y^{\mathcal{T}}$ *spills over* to the overfit between ($X^{\mathcal{T}}\hat{\beta}$ and $X^{\mathcal{T}}\beta$) and ($X^{\mathcal{T}}\hat{\beta}$ and $\epsilon^{\mathcal{T}}$).